# SharePoint 2010 out of microsoft support

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, support

Now that SharePoint 2019 is being released soon, when can we expect the SharePoint 2010 being out of Microsoft`s support?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft ends mainstream support for SharePoint 2010 on **oct 13 2015.**

Now product is already on the extended support which will be end on **10/13/2020**

Read complete detail from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/14944